# PHP include path problem

Tags: php, include, apache2, include-path

I have set apache so that all requests go to a file /var/www/common_index.php

Now, common_index.php looks at requested file name and sources appropriate file 
/var/www/123/public_html/requested_file.php

I am having problems when I include a file (with relative path) in requested_file.php. It tries to search for file in /var/www  instead of /var/www/123/public_html/

How to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [change the working directory](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) in `requested_file.php` before calling `include` to make it work:

```
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
include 'path/to/file.php';
```

or for PHP 5.3+

```
chdir(__DIR__);
include 'path/to/file.php';
```

If you don't want to change the working directory (which will affect other file system operations) then just append the path each time you do an include using the [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) `__DIR__`:

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/path/to/file.php';
include __DIR__ . '/path/to/file.php'; # for PHP 5.3+
```

where the path is relative to the file where you used the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your DocumentRoot in your Apache config.

Set it to `/var/www/123/`

Comment: Then how do I ensure that all requests go to /var/www/common_index.php ? (I need it for some reason). Also... the public_html path varies....

Answer (score 0):

You can use `__DIR__`:

```
$path = __DIR__;
```

Whereas `$path` contains the path of the file which contains this line